# How to convert c# DLL to vb DLL

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

Please, can I convert a c# DLL to vb DLL,  My problem is when I try to use svg.dll written in c# with a vb Code, Single and Float Types don't much, Any Help or suggestion !

Comment: There is no need for conversion if you use a compatible .NET version.

Comment: are you sure it is a .NET C# DLL and not something else?

Comment: This question don't much.

Comment: I've tried to use it without conversion but I couldn't  use functions that have float parameters 
@Plutonix Yes, I am sur

Comment: What specific error message do you get when using those functions? Please share the relevant code.

Answer (score 4):

Good news: There is no need to convert! A .NET DLL is neither a C# DLL nor a VB.NET DLL, it's simply a .NET DLL. You can use DLLs created with C# in VB.NET and vice-versa.

*(Apparently, you have some specific issue using a third-party DLL. Now that you know that "the language of the DLL" is not the problem, I suggest that you start a new question about that and explain the problems you are having in detail. Beware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/138661)!)*